# Agora.io React Native SDK issue: cannot find symbol method

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I am with a bad problem that I can't resolve.
I am trying to make exactly what is written in this git readme: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RTC-SDK-for-React-Native
I am trying to run this sample on my phone, that is connected by USB.
But at the end of the steps, when I try to Run it on android studio, it shows this message:
[image]
I tried delete this lines from the file but other errors appears.
Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, and i realize in latest agora sdk they deprecated monitorConnectionEvent and setSpeakerphoneVolume method.

I deleted those two method from AgoraModule.java and it worked for me.

Here is few thing to check:

1. Make sure you are using latest agora sdk.
2. As of today agora team already update the code in the git repo, so you can simply copy AgoraModule.java from [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO/React-Native-SDK/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/rnapi/AgoraModule.java) and replace with your local.

It should works.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove the Monitor connection method and setspeakervolume method. Both of these have been removed from the latest agora sdks.
Remove them from the file and ull run fine.

Also check if you are using the latest files regarding the apk.
Find them on github or refer to the website.